# clojure: initialize 2d vector

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

in clojure I'm using the following function to initialize a 2d vector:

```
(defn vec2d [x y init]
  (vec (map 
         #(vec (map init (range x))) (range y))))
```

usage:

```
(def grid (vec2d 40 30 (fn [] "x")))
```

Since I'm new to the language, I ask myself if this is the most straight-forward way to do so. Has anyone an idea to optimize this?

Comment: This is pretty confusing.  What are you trying to put in and what do you want to get out?

Comment: sorry, there was something wrong in the code. now it's updated.

Comment: If you're doing a lot with 2D structures, you may want to consider core.matrix.

Answer (score 3):

Under the assumption that you'll always want to initialize the entries of the vector to a constant, here's how I'd do this:

```
(defn vec2d
  "Return an x by y vector with all entries equal to val."
  [x y val]
  (vec (repeat y (vec (repeat x val)))))
```

Answer (score 2):

if you want to be able to initialize according to the coordinate, you could do this

```
(defn vec2d [sx sy f]
  (mapv (fn[x](mapv (fn[y] (f x y)) (range sx))) (range sy)))
```

This allows you to have a constant value if you do

```
(vec2d 4 3 (constantly 2))
;; [[2 2 2 2] [2 2 2 2] [2 2 2 2]]
```

or initialize according to the coordinates, say:

```
(vec2d 4 3 (fn[x y] (+ x y))) 
(vec2d 4 3 +)                         ;; or more concisely
;;[[0 1 2 3] [1 2 3 4] [2 3 4 5]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `mapv` and you're set

```
(defn vec2d [x y init]
  (mapv #(mapv init (range x)) (range y)))
```

If you want the coordinates for initialization:

```
(defn vec2d [x y init]
  (mapv (fn [y] (mapv #(init % y) (range x))) (range y))
```

A nested for it's also very readable for boards generation if you just want all cells:

```
(defn vec2d [cols rows init]
  (for [x (range rows) y (range cols)]
    (init x y)))
```

Or if you don't mind seqs:

```
(defn vec2d [cols rows init]
  (for [x (range rows)]
    (for [y (range cols)]
      (init x y))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a threading macro:

```
(defn vec-2d [r c v] (->> (repeat c v) vec (repeat r) vec))
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).